# Adding extra fan on my setup. please advice on proper Exhaust or Intake of Fan

Tags: fan, cooling, overclocking

I modified my computer case so that I can add more computer fan to make my computer cool this summer. I  need your thoughts on how I can improve my idea and I'm open to all of your advice.

Status:

[image]

Fan Position (The blue circles are the fan's location)

[image]

At the side I have to intake blowing fresh air at the motherboard and at the top and back I have Exhaust fan blowing out hot air. The computer fans will be powered by 12v adapter (recycled) so that my power supply wouldn't be overloaded. I need some practical advice, I don't want to spend to much on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cold(er) air should **enter the front** and warm air should **exit the back** of the PC.  This is to ensure that maximum heat is taken up by the air as it travels through the box and that the air keeps moving and doesn't become *stuck* swirling inside the box.

Some PCs also have cool air **intakes** above the CPU.  This is to ensure the CPU always has cool air even if the items at the front of the PC (hard drives) are warming the front intake air.

For interesting reading on the subject of efficient transfer, look up how fish's gills work.  They put CO2 into water but transferring heat into air is a similar process (in terms of flow). ;-)

Comment: Don't bother with the top of the box as it's most likely blocked by the power supply and CD-ROM drive any way.  Also you would be diverting air in a way the manufacturer did not intend.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you know you're already on a tight power budget, it'd probably be easier to just connect the fans to the computer's power supply. Entirely up to you I suppose.

If you have the tools, I'd recommend placing an additional intake fan in the bottom front, between the case and the hard drives I'm assuming are directly behind that lower area.